# AWS Lmbda TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 21, 46, 24, 862000) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to return an outfit from m RDS database. The dte fields are all formatted in DATETIME which is causing me to get the following error:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 21, 46, 24, 862000) is not JSON serializable
```

How can I get around this?

heres my code:

```
import pymysql
import json
from rds import *

#rds settings
host  = rds_host
name = rds_name
password = rds_password
db_name = rds_db_name
port = rds_port

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host = host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)

except:
    raise Exception('Database Error: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.')


def handler(event, context):

    cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    #selects a user from the database
    query = "SELECT * FROM Outfits WHERE outfit_id = '" + event['outfitId'] + "' LIMIT 1"
    #runs the SQL query
    try:
        cur.execute(query)
    except:
        raise Exception('Internal Error: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.')

    #stores the downloaded record into the user variable
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    return result
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question given above.  

The OP has no control over _how_ AWS converts the MySQL query to Json, as it is done outside of the Lambda function by AWS itself.  

As a result, the fix needs to be done on the query results themselves rather than modifying the JSON encoder (as there is no guarentee how AWS converts the results to a JSON string).

Answer (score 5):

Haven't used AWS Lambda but this issue is python specific. `datetime.datetime` objects cannot be JSON serialized, you need to convert them to strings before JOSN serializing. You can use [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to convert your `datetime.datetime` objects to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not store the datetime in a different format? looks like the response from querying the database is JSON format, storing the date as a string would be much more efficient surely?

Comment: But i then need to query to database, getting results ordered by date and therefore need the datetime format to do this